# Using Angular + JQuery for a Dynamic Pinterest-Style Layout

Tags: jquery, dynamic, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pinterest

I'm relatively new to Angular and have very little experience with JQuery, so whatever insight/advice you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

My goal is to build a dynamic Pinterest-style layout that filters on the fly as users type in their query.  I've managed to hack together something moderately functional here:

http://plnkr.co/IW9FBA3KO0uYfl8WNCno

[Note: this is based on the excellent work done by Ben Holland [here](http://benholland.me/javascript/how-to-build-a-site-that-works-like-pinterest/)

I essentially have two questions about the marriage of Angular & JQuery:

1. I have most of the app logic running in the controller, but I'm guessing a better way to achieve this would be via a directive?
2. Is there a way to do this without using Jquery and just using Angular's new animation features?

Thanks again for any guidance you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pinterest style arrangement you can build it using jquery.popbild.js.Just take a look at it.Its the easiest tutorial you can find.

Download the project from ->  http://funscripts.popbild.com/jquery_popbild/